# How do I show a select Item in xaml c#

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, selecteditem

I want to change the selected item in my listview, therfore I have changed the listView.SelectedItem, but now the selection is not shown in the xaml Window but the value for selectedItem is set.
How can I show the selection on the xaml window?

"schueler" is my listview

```
//save the value of the old datasource
        XmlElement selectet = (XmlElement)schueler.SelectedItem;
        string name = selectet.GetAttribute("MachineId");

        //Refreshing the datasource
        XmlDataProvider oProv = schueler.DataContext as XmlDataProvider;
        oProv.Refresh();

        //Select old 
        for (int i = 0; i < schueler.Items.Count; i++ )
        {
            XmlElement item = (XmlElement)schueler.Items.GetItemAt(i);
            Console.WriteLine(item.GetAttribute("MachineId"));
            if(item.GetAttribute("MachineId")==name)
            {
                schueler.SelectedItem = schueler.Items.GetItemAt(i);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It would be very helpfull when you show us what you've tried.

Comment: Wait, what do you want to achieve? I dont understand.

Comment: I have an xml where I get my data for the list view, now I want to update the source because chages were made in the xml file. After reloading the datasource, I want to select the old value in the datasource, so that the user don't have to select it again after a refresh of the datasource

Comment: @Mirra See the answer, the edited version should work for you.